# Android-Zoom a imageView when it got Focused

Tags: android

I am new Android. I have declared the imageView in xml file.I want to get zoom in and out when the image is get focused.there is any way to zoom a   static image view in android. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to zoom in and zoom out :http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29